# why dmesg output to log file is not working?

Tags: command-line, bash, syslog, dmesg

I am trying to output the dmesg to a log file so I can look at it through my txt editor, but i keep getting an error msg:

dmesg > /Desktop/log.txt

gives me this error: 
bash: /Desktop/dmesg.log: No such file or directory

I have also tried: dmesg >> /Desktop/log.txt
but i get the same error message.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `/Desktop/` folder by default, and there shouldn’t be one.

To access the `Desktop` folder in your user's home folder use either the full `/home/your_username/Desktop/` (replace `your_username` with your actual user name) or the shorter `~/Desktop/`.

So

```
dmesg > ~/Desktop/log.txt
```

should do what you want.